# How to get version id of AWS codebuild artifact that is uploaded to S3?

Tags: aws-codebuild

I have an AWS Codebuild that gets the code from GitHub and after a successful build, it uploads the artefact to an s3 bucket. The bucket has versioning enabled. I want to create a new git release tag after every successful build which will contain the s3 version id of the artefact uploaded. How is that achievable?

My buildspec.yaml looks as follows

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo install phase started on `date`
      - npm i
  build:
    commands:
      - echo build started on `date`
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo post_build started on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

Comment: What does your Project artifact configuration look like?

Comment: @Unsigned above-mentioned buildspec is the exact one I am using. It zips everything after `npm install`.